# Spring roo jams at create new spring roo project

Tags: spring, spring-roo

just wanted to know if anyone had encountered this problem in the past and whether they had resolved it. 
I use the STS program on my mac but any time I try to create a new roo project the program stalls at packaging the JAR files. Please refer to the image below thanks

[image]

Comment: What is the version of Spring Roo and STS you are using? :)

Comment: @bhagyas hey buddy, im using 3.2.0.RELEASE for sts and 1.2.3 for spring roo :D

Comment: Are you able to run the STS with better virtual memory? Does this happen when you run using the Roo shell as well?

Comment: i believe i always have enough visual memory when carrying this out. And no it doesnt happen when using the Roo shell, when i import a project from svn the roo shell works as it should but when i try to create a new roo project locally it stalls :( @bhagyas